# How to get Items from ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, itemssource

I am using a custom control that has an ItemsSource. I have bound the ItemsSource to a CollectionViewSource in XAML. That CollectionViewSource is bound to a List.

Now I want to get all the Items from the ItemsSource but that control doesn't have a property Items (like GridView or ListView has). So I have to manually get the items from the ItemsSource.

The ItemsSource is an object, but when I put a breakpoint to check what value is stored in the ItemsSource i get this: Windows Runtime Object. So my question again: How to get the Items from this ItemsSource?

Comment: Can you post a relevant part of your code so that people who read this post can help you better?

Comment: You mean the `Source` property is a Windows Runtime Object? Some code would help clarify. Is it possible to inherit from ItemsControl? That would give you an Items dependency property for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution:

valueList = (myControl.ItemsSource as ICollectionView).ToList();